# Detect UK holidays in date data

Tags: r

I am working in  R, I have 20 years data and I would to check if every giving date is a UK holiday creating a categorical variable (TRUE/FALSE).

I used this code:

```
library(timeDate)
c <- timeDate(data$Date)    
b <- isHoliday(c, holidays = GBBankHoliday(), wday = 1:6)
```

or

```
b <- isHoliday(c, holidays = HolidayLONDON(), wday = 1:6)
```

but it detecs only Sundays (not Christmass or other Holidays).
Does anyone have an idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating wrapper functions for various holidays in the package, and extracting the dates for the holidays, and cross-referencing those dates for your analysis:

```
library(timeDate)
c <- timeDate(data$Date)    
b <- isHoliday(c, holidays = GBBankHoliday(), wday = 1:6)

years <- list(Year = c(2019,2018,2017,2016))

year_fun <- function(year){timeDate::.easter(year)}

purrr::map(years, year_fun)

$Year
GMT
[1] [2019-04-21] [2018-04-01] [2017-04-16] [2016-03-27]
```

Comment: I would need to see your data for the next step, but for equality matches there is a range of approaches, such as joining or filtering.

Comment: Thank you for your ansewer. It does extract the holidays but I dont need to extract them. I need to create a variable (TRUE/FALSE) for each day form 1991 to 2000 (i.e. True if is a holiday in UK False if is not)

Answer (score 0):

I created a new binary variable in my data which is called "holiday". If the date of my data is a UK holiday the value is 1 (TRUE) if the date is not a holiday the value is 2 (FALSE). The code is very simple:

```
library(timeDate)
data$holidays<-as.factor(data$Date %in% (as.Date(holidayLONDON(1990:2010))))
```